# content.js:1 (anonymous function) - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typeerror, anonymous-function

I'm trying to put together a chrome extension that blocks everything on youtube's homepage except for the search bar.

I am getting the errors mentioned in the title in my google chrome extensions manager when I am on Youtube, after I click on the Chrome Extension's icon.

My index.js code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("primary").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("contents").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("guide").style.display = "none";
```

any idea as to how I can get the error messages from cropping up?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4OkX.png)

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The element probably doesn't exist yet, my guess is it's created by JavaScript

Comment: By injecting CSS, you can also hide elements created in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This sample injects CSS to hide the element.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "css": [
        "matches.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.css

```css
#primary,
#contents,
#guide {
  display: none;
}
```